# How to define bind_result with dynamic variables?

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to automate the construction of a query executing in PHP, using a datas array.
But for the bind_result, I have no idea how to do this...

I have this simple SQL query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, username, email FROM users';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $email ;
```

I added this array:

```
$configTable = array(
    array(
        'th' => '#',
        'data' => 'id'
    ),
    array(
        'th' => 'Username',
        'data' => 'username'
    ),
    array(
        'th' => 'Email',
        'data' => 'email'
    )
);
```

And I try to use theses data. For the SQL, no problem:

```
$fields = implode(', ', $configSql['fields']);
$sql = 'SELECT '.$fields.' FROM '.$configSql['table'];
```

But for the bind_result, I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: Don't use `bind_result()` in the first place. Use `$result->fetch_assoc()` to get an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [the manual page for `bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) notes:

> This functions is useful for simple results. To retrieve iterable result set, or fetch each row as an array or object, use mysqli_stmt_get_result().

When you're working with dynamic data, using individual variables is almost never the most effective solution; instead, you want an array or object with appropriate fields.

Probably the most useful is to get an associative array for each row, where the keys are column names:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$formattedResult = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Now you have a plain PHP array, which you can format into an HTML table or whatever you need, e.g.

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach ( $configTable as $field ) {
   echo "<th>", htmlspecialchars($field['th']), "</th>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
    echo "<tr>"\n;
    foreach ( $configTable as $field ) {
       $value = $row[ $field['data'] ];
       echo "<th>", htmlspecialchars($value), "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```